# Lateral Column only for comments or pictures

Tags: columns

How can I create a document (book) with a lateral column for comments or show pictures like the example? It´s not a simple two column document! The main text is showed only in the "main" column. The sample is from Larson's Calculus book.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The `memoir` class and its marginfigure might be interesting.

Comment: Have a look at the `Tufte-book` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I´ll try.

Comment: Did you find a suitable class/way to replicate the example you provided?